# WSO2 AS - Secure Vault in webapp and jndi

Tags: wso2, jndi, wso2-as

I want to store a password for an api endpoint that will be used for any webapps.

In the file `catalina-server.xml` I put the following configuration

```
...
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <Environment name="paci/connectionUrl" type="java.lang.String" value="http://10.0.0.1:1234/paci/v1.0"/>
    <Environment name="paci/adminUser" type="java.lang.String" value="admin"/>
    <Environment name="paci/adminPass" svns:secretAlias="Paci.AdminUser.Password" type="java.lang.String" value="password"/>
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

I configured secure vault using this [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon441/Encrypting+Passwords+with+Cipher+Tool%20doc) for using the Cipher Tool.

`cipher-tool.properties`

```
Paci.AdminUser.Password=repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml//Server/GlobalNamingResources/Environment[@name='paci/adminPass'][@value],true
```

`cipher-text.properties`

```
Paci.AdminUser.Password=EnCrYpTeDvAlUe123
```

In the web-app I had to add link to the global resource in the `META-INF/context.xml` to make JNDI to resolve.

```
...
<Context>
    <ResourceLink global="paci/connectionUrl" name="paci/connectionUrl" type="java.lang.String" />
    <ResourceLink global="paci/adminUser" name="paci/adminUser" type="java.lang.String" />
    <ResourceLink global="paci/adminPass" name="paci/adminPass" type="java.lang.String" />
</Context>
```

Here is my code:

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
String paciPass = (String) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/paci/adminPass");
```

The value of `paciPass` is "password" and not the encrypted password. I don't know why the vault is not returning the encrypted pass.

What I have to do to the secure vault in wso2 resolve the alias in the JNDI?

Comment: The last two sentences are not ver clear. Could you please explain little more?

Comment: I edited the question, see if it is clear now. The problem is to make the secret alias to work in catalina-server.xml and use it with jndi.